# What type is that glass?

Tags: replacement-parts, dlp

I own a [Magic Build 3D Printer](http://www.magicbuild3dprinter.com/). I found out, that the glass is scratched like in the picture.

So, I'm looking for a replacement glass plane to put in front of the projector. Is this a special glass? What are the properties? Where can I find it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sheet of glass you'd most likely need to acquire as a replacement part **for your printer's manufacturer**:

- The dimensions of the glass, especially with the rounded corners, are usually very odd and make buying a spare from a glassmaker really expensive.
- Some printers like the Elegoo Mars have an LCD mounted as part of this sheet.
- Printers also might have this plate coated for different properties, for example, to reduce reflectivity and refraction inside the printer.

In this case, we have a DLP setup that uses a projector. You best inquire at the manufacturer itself using their [website](http://www.magicbuild3dprinter.com/iletisim/), [E-Mail](http://sales@yourcompany.com) or [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/magicbuild3D/) about a few spare pieces - that will get you the same quality as the bed you already had (save for the scratches) and they usually have such items in stock.